# Tomar texto de un JtextField y mostrarlo en mayusculas en otro textfield (java)

Tags: java, jtextfield

tengo un programa en donde el usuario debe digitar su nombre en un textfield y mostrarle el nombre que digito en mayusculas en otro textfield. Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora pero hago hecha bolas con la parte de convertir a mayusculas y mostrarlo en el otro textfield. Como puedo lograr esto?`

```js
import javax.swing.*;
public class nombre  extends JFrame
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
  {
new nombre();
}
public nombre()
{
JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
JLabel label1=new JLabel("Ingrese su Nombre");
JTextField txt1=new JTextField(20);
JLabel label2=new JLabel("Nombre");
JTextField txt2=new JTextField(20);
String texto = txt1.getText();




panel1.add(label1);
panel1.add(txt1);
panel1.add(label2);
panel1.add(txt2);

this.add(panel1);
this.setTitle("Programa");
this.setSize(350,500);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya obtienes el dato, puedes hacerlo mayúscula con la siguiente linea de código:

```
txt1.toUpperCase()
```

**toUpperCase()** es el método que nos ayuda a hacer eso que necesitas.